# What is difference between running mongodb with "Sudo service mongod start " and mongod -f </pathToConf File>

Tags: mongodb

I have Replica set running with command "Sudo service mongod start" , i killed all mongod process using "kill" command after that i run replicaSet with (mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf), Now if i tries to run same replicaSet with "sudo service mongod start" after killing them  again gives me error.

Output:

sudo service mongod start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mongod.service
Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

systemctl status mongod.service:

● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-10-29 12:24:40 PDT; 23s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

Process: 4841 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Process: 4838 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Process: 4836 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Process: 4831 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Main PID: 4558 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 29 12:24:40 centos systemd[1]: Starting High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database...

Oct 29 12:24:40 centos mongod[4841]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.

Oct 29 12:24:40 centos mongod[4841]: forked process: 4844

Oct 29 12:24:40 centos mongod[4841]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1

Oct 29 12:24:40 centos mongod[4841]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.

Oct 29 12:24:40 centos systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1

Oct 29 12:24:40 centos systemd[1]: Failed to start High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.

Oct 29 12:24:40 centos systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.

Oct 29 12:24:40 centos systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.

Thanks!